# fastify: stream closed prematurely

Tags: node.js, fastify

I'm trying to send an image as a stream...

```
  const { Readable } = require("stream");
  ...
  fastify.get(
    "/v1/files/:cid",
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {
      const { cid }: { cid: string } = request.params;
      const ipfs = create();
      const readableStream = Readable({
        async read() {
          for await (const chunk of ipfs.cat(cid)) {
            this.push(chunk);
          }
          this.push(null);
        },
      });
      reply.type("image/png").send(readableStream);
    }
  );
```

also tried

```
      const readableStream = new Readable();
      readableStream.read = () => {};
      for await (const chunk of ipfs.cat(cid)) {
        readableStream.push(chunk);
      }
```

The info I get is...

```
[17:31:38.006] INFO (44857): stream closed prematurely
    reqId: "req-1"
    res: {
      "statusCode": 200
    }
[17:31:38.006] INFO (44857): request completed
    reqId: "req-1"
    res: {
      "statusCode": 200
    }
    responseTime: 28.260344982147217
```

and when I check the headers

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 0.0.0.0:4000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
-------
Connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0
content-type: image/png
Date: Sun, 09 Oct 2022 16:44:07 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=72
vary: Origin
------
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
cp-extension-installed: Yes
Host: 0.0.0.0:4000
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to return the `reply` object because you manage the response using the `send` function. Here the details [from the docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#async-await).

```
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {
      const { cid }: { cid: string } = request.params;
      const ipfs = create();
      const readableStream = Readable({
        async read() {
          for await (const chunk of ipfs.cat(cid)) {
            this.push(chunk);
          }
          this.push(null);
        },
      });
      reply.type("image/png").send(readableStream);
      return reply
    }
```

Or:

```
      reply.type("image/png")
      return readableStream
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing this out & linking to the docs  an alternative I just tested from the docs would be `await reply.send(readableStream);` this way you could even do stuff like logging after serving the client 

Comment: Or, from what I understand `reply.send(readableStream);` and then later `await reply;`

Comment: not figuring this out before finding your answer made me almost leave fastify 